# fdhost.exe crashes on Windows XP systems (possible only on Toshiba R500 models)

Tags: sql-server

We have an application that uses SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services.

In an use case the application loads a large number of documents in the database (mainly .PDF, .HTML, .DOC and .XLS). For performance reasons, the application disables the free-text indexes before starting the load and enables it back when the load has finished.

On some Toshiba R500 systems the following error appears quite often: "The instruction at 0x04000609C referenced memory at 0x00000014. The memory could not be read.".

The instruction address may vary, but the memory address the process has tried to read is always 0x00000014.

The message appears when the application enables the full-text indexes.

Our application works fine, but the customer complains about the error message.

Also, it is possible that the free-text search scenarios do not work (we haven't tested this yet).

Do you have more informations on this issue?

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems at least part of the problem is known to Microsoft. They've given us an update (named CU6) and they're now checking some dumps to detect which IFilter module is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft support says the culprit is the Adobe IFilter module delivered with version 9.4.2.